# PHP: How to Auto Include & Instantiate Classes?

Tags: php, oop

There are a list of PHP files in the same directory of my script. They all follow a naming convention (e.g. class.foo.php). When my script runs, I want it to include those files. It's simple enough to do a `scandir` of the files, do a test in each item in the resulting array, and `include` the file.

The problem is how do I create an instance of those classes in my script (which is a class, also)? The file `class.foo.php` will have `class Foo` in it. I need to create an instance of `Foo` (and sometimes just access a static method). I can't do this in the running script because it is not aware of the auto-included classes.

`get_included_files` is useless because because it returns all the included files in the chain of classes (and I'm only interested in the classes included in the running script).

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way. What's a way for me to "auto include" class files and use them in the running script?

Comment: you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Create an autoload function and register it: [**spl_autoload_register**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

A proper autoload function will load the corresponding file when a class is instantiated.

Example from php.net:

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I'm still a bit confused. If I do `$a = new MyClass;` and `MyClass` isn't already included, the autoload function will try to find the appropriate file (in your example, the `classes/' . $class . '.class.php'` file), which should allow me to create an instance of that class. Great -- except I do not know these classes are. Do I `scandir` for the files and create instance from the results (I'll do the necessary filtering, of course) and just expect the autoloader to handle including on the fly?

Comment: Why would you not know what the classes or files are?  You are using random files or classes in your code?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, so long as the filenames of your classes are the same as the class name of the class being defined by that file, then your method will be passed all filenames to find the one that matches the class being searched for. ie: The above function shown by @Devon will find and load all files that $class = to the declared class name in the file ending with .class.php.   eg: filename= AclassFile.class.php  && class declaration in the file "class AclassFile" will be automatically made available for all classes in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__autoload()` magic method. See this example:

./myClass.php

```
<?php
class myClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "myClass init'ed successfuly!!!";
    }
}

?>
```

./index.php

```
<?php
// we've writen this code where we need
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./". $classname .".php";
    include_once($filename);
}

// we've called a class ***
$obj = new myClass();
?>
```

Output:

```
myClass init'ed successfuly!!!
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Comment: Please note the right direction is to use *spl_autoload_register* as *__autoload* was deprecated

Comment: @FredericYesidPeñaSánchez can you provide me a link with this info? I just read the php manual and I can't found this information about the deprecated

Comment: `__autoload()` gets messy when when you need more than one autoloader, for example in the case of another library.

Comment: Please read first tip on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php, the recommendation is *spl_autoload_register*

Comment: This method was deprecated in 7.2